# is it possible to simulate sign-in from the trusted app so that azure would establish a session without any UI interaction?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Let's say we have two websites, A and B
additionally, we have a mobile app C
All three use Azure AD B2C

Let's say a user X is authenticated in the mobile app C only (via Azure AD B2C). Then, the user X clicks at "go to the website A" from the mobile UI. We want to get X authenticated on A automatically just based on the fact that X was authenticated successfully in the mobile app.

For that, we can create a special autologin URL receiving a signed JWT where UID (X's) is encoded. "A" would extract the UID from JWT and open a local session in which X is authenticated.

Great. But. What if X goes to the website B and clicks a "sign in" there? In this case, the user X will be redirected to the Azure AD B2C where no active session will have been set yet, and the user X will need to re-enter a username and password again to open the session. We remember that X has already done it in the mobile app once, what's the point to get authenticated again on "C"?

It would be great if the Azure AD B2C session can be opened by that special autologin page in some specific way so that the second sign-in would authenticate the user X without presenting a login form. For example, a JWT token would be sent to Azure AD B2C so that Azure would sign that user in as if the user entered a username and password, and redirected the user to the website ("C"). In this case, no forms would be displayed after the second "sign-in". But it seems that such flow is not possible with the Azure.

But how to implement it, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the webview to authenticate, the user would get SSO on all apps on the mobile. There’s nothing to implement, it’s default behaviour.

If you tried it and it’s not working, it might because you are not passing a login_hint parameter with MSAL library. Try pass a dummy value into this.

Comment: but the session on the Azure AD B2C side will exist only in the (integrated) browser used by the mobile app rather than in the (standalone, external) browser launched when a link is clicked from the mobile app?

Comment: Nope. In both iOS and Android, the default MSAL libraries use webviews which share cookies across the system.

Comment: iOS reference for example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/customize-webviews#cookie-sharing-and-single-sign-on-sso-implications

Comment: that's really useful. Thanks